# How to convert current date and time of Bangladesh into Bangla Language using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have a time  like **Sat Feb 10 2024 15:33:51 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)** . I want to convert the time into Bangla language. For example **সময়: ০৯:৫৯, মঙ্গলবার, ২৬ ডিসেম্বর, ২০২৩ ১২ পৌষ ১৪৩০ বঙ্গাব্দ, ০৯:৫৯ পূর্বাহ্ন**

how to do this using JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat):

```js
console.log(
  new Intl.DateTimeFormat(
    "bn", // Bengali
    {
      dateStyle: "full",
      timeStyle: "full",
      hour12: false,
      timeZone: "Asia/Dhaka", // Bangladesh Standard Time
    }
  )
  .format(
    new Date("2024-02-10T09:33:51.000Z")
  )
)
```

You can also further customise [which date-time components to show and in which format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat#date-time_component_options).

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing Bangladesh language and Suggest the following code.
Create a function that maps English month names, days, and numbers to their Bengali equivalents, and then formatting the date string accordingly.

```js
function convertToBanglaDate(dateString) {
    const monthsInBangla = [
        'বৈশাখ', 'জ্যৈষ্ঠ', 'আষাঢ়', 'শ্রাবণ', 'ভাদ্র', 'আশ্বিন',
        'কার্তিক', 'অগ্রহায়ণ', 'পৌষ', 'মাঘ', 'ফাল্গুন', 'চৈত্র'
    ];

    const daysInBangla = [
        'শনিবার', 'রবিবার', 'সোমবার', 'মঙ্গলবার', 'বুধবার', 'বৃহস্পতিবার', 'শুক্রবার'
    ];

    const numbersInBangla = ['০','১','২','৩','৪','৫','৬','৭','৮','৯'];

    const date = new Date(dateString);

    const day = daysInBangla[date.getDay()];
    const month = monthsInBangla[date.getMonth()];
    const year = date.getFullYear().toString().replace(/[0-9]/g, digit => numbersInBangla[digit]);
    const hour = date.getHours().toString().replace(/[0-9]/g, digit => numbersInBangla[digit]);
    const minute = date.getMinutes().toString().replace(/[0-9]/g, digit => numbersInBangla[digit]);

    return `সময়: ${hour}:${minute}, ${day}, ${date.getDate()} ${month}, ${year} ${date.getFullYear()} বঙ্গাব্দ, ${hour}:${minute} ${hour < 12 ? 'পূর্বাহ্ন' : 'অপরাহ্ণ'}`;
}

const englishDate = "Sat Feb 10 2024 15:33:51 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time)";
const banglaDate = convertToBanglaDate(englishDate);
console.log(banglaDate);
```

Comment: @23329000 everything showing wrong. I want to show sat 10 feb 2024 in bangla , and also the bengali calender's date and year.

Comment: @ShabnamSabah—if you want the Bengali calendar, you should edit your question to include that important detail. For some strange reason, available calendars are related to languages (which are misnamed "locales" in various ECMA standards). `new Intl.Locale('bn').getCalendars()` returns `["gregory", "islamic", "islamic-civil", "islamic-tbla"]`. Do any of those equate to the Bengali calendar?